# Loop animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, setinterval

**NEED THIS IN JS**

I'm trying to make an animation that slides a cloud from right side of box to left side. With this in mind, the cloud should appear as fading in and fading out at each side. The fading should be whilst the cloud is moving.

I'm trying to make this a continious animation without calling it recursively by using setInterval.

However, for some reason - this is not working, I've linked example and code. https://jsfiddle.net/tes1ey3L/2/

The exmaple is not working, but you get the idea. - Fade in whilst sliding to the other side and fading out. Then all over again.

```js
animateC();
setInterval(animateC(),35000);

function animateC() {
    $('#animationCloud').css('left', '680px');
    $('#animationCloud').parent().animate({queue:false, opacity: 1 }, 5000, 'linear');
    $('#animationCloud').animate({ left: -161 }, 35000, 'linear');
    $('#animationCloud').parent().delay(25000).animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 5000, 'linear');
}
```

```css
#container {
    width: 680px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: 170px;
}

#animationCloud {
    background-color: white;
    width: 161px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    line-height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}

#parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="animationCloud">
            Im a cloud
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using CSS animation?

```css
.bg {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.cloud {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 100px 0;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    animation-name: move;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes move {
    0% {
        left: 0%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    80% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        left: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="cloud">I'm in a cloud!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Might want to leave out the `animation-direction: alternate`, to more closely match the expected behaviour

Comment: @StephenTG I was under the impression he wanted it to go back and forth, but if he wants it to always start from one direction and go to the other then you are correct.

Comment: need it in JS, as I'm storing current pos as localstorage, and hereby having the animation start from where it was left when going to another page.

Comment: @RasmusHjorthLüdeking that would have been good to put into your initial question then. :)

Answer (score 0):

Function `setInterval` should be implement without `()` after function.

I fixed your code. Try to use something like this:

```
function animateC() {
    $('#animationCloud').css('left', '680px');
    $('#animationCloud').parent().animate({queue:false, opacity: 1 }, 3000, 'linear');
    $('#animationCloud').animate({ left: -161 }, 3000, 'linear');
    $('#animationCloud').parent().delay(1000).animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 3000, 'linear');
}

animateC();
setInterval(animateC,3100);
```

Comment: not working, stops after 1 run, check linked fiddle.

Comment: I updated post, try it now and adjust to fit your needs

Comment: By making a difference in timeout to actual time of function, it bugs somewhere along 3rd-5th run. It will skip one run for some reason and remain at left: -161px for 35000 sec. https://jsfiddle.net/tes1ey3L/3/